# Needs python or jupyter notebook helper hand image splitter

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook

I am working with Chest X-Ray14 dataset. The data contains about 112,200 images grouped in 12 folders (i.e. images1 to images12) The image labels are in a csv file called Data_Entry_2017.csv. I want to split the images base on the csv labels (attribute "Finding Labels) into their their various train and test folders.

Can anyone help me with Python or Jupyter-notebook split code? I will be grateful.

Comment: Can you give one example of how you want to split?

Comment: The images are grouped in 12 folder but have their annotations in csv file. The CSV file has the attribute "Image Index, Finding Labels" where the image index correspond to the images name in the image folder and the Finding Labels are the various labels to the particular image. I would like to use the Image Index and Finding Labels attribute from the CSV to split the images to their various classes in the train and test folders. This is the link to the CSV file (Data_Entry_2017.csv) http://academictorrents.com/details/557481faacd824c83fbf57dcf7b6da9383b3235a.

Comment: So how does the row mentioning labels for 3 rd image in the 4th folder written in CSV?

Comment: The image folders are named "images_001 , images_002 to images_012. The 3rd image   in the folder is labelled under Image Index as '00006585_009.png' and Finding Label as Infiltration

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.rread_csv("Data_Entry_2017.csv")
infiltration_df = df[df["Finding Label"]=="Infiltration"]
list_infiltration = infiltration_df .index.values.tolist() # This will be a list of image names
```

Then you can parse each folder and check if image name is in the list of infiltration labels, you can put that in different folders.

To read all image filenames in a folder, you can use **os.listdir**

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
imagefiles = [f for f in listdir(image_folder_name) if isfile(join(image_folder_name, f))]
```

For train test split you can refer [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Comment: Can you help me with script to pass in the source images, destination folders and the train and test percentage split?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a snippet. You can check the code and the link attached. Do mark as answered if you find the answer useful.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want a full script where I can pass in the destination, train and test split percentage.